# Entity Framework 7 composite keys in migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying MVC 6, Entity Framework 7 and ASP.NET Identity for the first time.
I just generated a default project and I'm changing the login process to support accounts by tenant, based on the following tutorial.

https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy

The thing is, when I try to change the initial migration to support a composite key (Id,TenentId) on the AspNetUsers table it simply fails with a generic message. 
The migration code is the following.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    TenantId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)                    
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ApplicationUser", x => new { x.Id, x.TenantId });
                });
```

I also tried the following code but it also doesn't work.

```
constraints: table =>
                    {
                        table.PrimaryKey("PK_ApplicationUser", x => x.Id);     
                        table.PrimaryKey("PK_ApplicationUser", x => x.TenantId);    
                    });
```

If I leave it as a non composite key the migration executes successfully.

```
constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ApplicationUser", x => x.Id);
                });
```

I tried to define a unique constraint over both columns but I wasn't able to find a way to do it.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Where are you putting that code?  In the OnModelCreating() override of the ApplicationUserDbContext class?

Comment: That's on the initial migration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any customization of the Identity tables needs to be done by creating derived classes of the Identity model classes and/or by creating a derived class from the `IdentityDbContext` class.

But I wouldn't try changing the primary key structure of the Identity tables.  I seriously doubt that will work and if it does, there's no gaurantee that it will work properly.

Just to get you pointed in the right direction, here's how I modified my IdentityUser class (AspNetUsers table).  I added a few properties to store data I retrieve from Active Directory.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Doing this requires that you create a derived class from the `IdentityDbContext` class that uses the model class above.  In mine I rename the Identity tables.

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        //Rename the ASP.NET Identity tables.
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRole");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserRoleClaim");
    }
}
```

Then in the ConfigureServices() method in Startup.cs

```
//Add Identity services.
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()  
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you added new attributes.
I aggree with you on the subject of not altering the key structure, it's going to be a pain changing the foreign keys on other tables. 
I think I'll just append the TenantId before the UserId, that way I won't have repeated users on the table.

Comment: You're welcome.  Ok, sounds like a plan.  How about an up vote?  I gave you one.  Maybe even mark it as the accepted answer if you agree that changing the primary keys is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks.  You could add the TenantId field and add a unique key constraint in the MyDbContext class.  It should probably work there.  I have one where I added a few new tables and added fields related to those tables in the Identity tables.  Then created foreign key constraints to my new tables.

Comment: I think that won't work. Since the UserId is the table key, it won't be possible to have two records of the same user for different tenants. That was what I was trying to do.